# Consuming Nuget packages with specific pre-release tag

Tags: nuget

In our dev environment, we have a Git repo which houses a common component. This repo has multiple feature branches which are publishing Nuget packages through a  CI build to a common feed. In the feed, packages coming from these feature branches are identified with a prerelease tag of the branch name. As a consumer, I am looking into this feed through sources mentioned in Nuget.config file. And, I am trying to consume packages coming from a particular feature branch of that common component. But the Nuget update command which I am calling from consumer project can potentially pull a pre-release version from other branch if that package has a higher version. Pls share your inputs on how to resolve this. I am not seeing any additional arguments in update command to mention the specific pre-release tag

Thanks

Sandeep

Answer (score 4):

There are a few options:

1. Use different feeds - clearly most complicated from the infrastructure point of view unless you can easily create feeds through a service. But this makes "update everything" commands easy.
2. Give those packages a different identity (name), so can publish `My.Product.With.FeatureA` and `My.Product.With.FeatureB`.
3. Use [`allowedVersions` in `packages.config`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/packages-config#schema) to restrict updates to a version range. For this you might also need to use different minor/patch versions and not only prerelease tags for packages.

When using the [new `PackageReference` format](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/nuget/NuGet-now-fully-integrated-into-MSBuild/#what-about-other-project-types-that-are-not-net-core) in VS 2017 15.1+ (already released), you have some more options

4. Use floating references for parts of the perelease tag. e.g. `1.2.3-coolfeatureA-*`.
5. Since `PackageReference` is used from MSBuild, you can also define a central feature and build version (e.g. in a `Directory.Build.props` file) and use these in package references. E.g. you could use definitions like this in your `csproj` file:

   ```
   <ItemGroup>
     <PackageReference Include="My.Shared.LibA" Version="1.2.3-$(LibsFeatureBranch)-$(LibsBuildNumber)" />
     <PackageReference Include="My.Shared.LibB" Version="1.2.3-$(LibsFeatureBranch)-$(LibsBuildNumber)" />
   </ItemGroup>
   ```

Together with a `Directory.Build.props` file (at project or solution level) containing:

```
    <Project>
      <PropertyGroup>
        <LibsFeatureBranch>CoolFeatureA</LibsFeatureBranch>
        <LibsBuildNumber>20170510-</LibsBuildNumber>
      </PropertyGroup>
    </Project>
```

Comment: Thanks so much Martin. I am trying to use allowedVersions. But I am not successful so far. I have 2 feature branches with version 2.0.0 which have tags sandeepf1 & sandeepf2. Both have published 2 Nuget packages so package versions are:
2.0.0-sandeepf11
2.0.0-sandeepf12
2.0.0-sandeepf21
2.0.0-sandeepf22
I need to consume latest version from sandeepf1 branch which is 2.0.0-sandeepf12. I have tried so many patterns in allowedVersions property but it is not able to get this version. 
[2.0.0-sandeepf1, 2.1.0-sandeepf1)  gets me 2.0.0-sandeepf22
[2.0.0-sandeepf1]  gets me 2.0.0-sandeepf11